# use two carousel in a page

Tags: javascript, html

i'm now designing a web use html and javascript. i would like to know how to use two image slider(carousel) in one page.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 5000);  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
 <img src="pic1.jpg" class="mySlides" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
 <img src="pic2.jpg" class="mySlides" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
 <img src="pic3.jpg" class="mySlides" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <!--another slider-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Although not a functional thing, if you declare variables as `x` or whatever, it makes it very, very difficult to follow. Use something semantic like `var carousel = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it many ways. 
This way, following the code you wrote, just use a class name that can be generated in a loop. For example:

```
class="slides1"
```

can be generated with:

```
var i=1
var class_name="slides"
class_name=class_name+i
```

I hope it helps!

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var caro_sel=1;
  
    for (caro_sel=1;caro_sel<=2;caro_sel++) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"+caro_sel);
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      myIndex++;
      if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
      x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
 
      setTimeout(carousel, 5000); 
    } 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
   <img src="pic1.jpg" class="mySlides1" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
   <img src="pic2.jpg" class="mySlides1" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
   <img src="pic3.jpg" class="mySlides1" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
    </td>
    <td>  
      <img src="pic1.jpg" class="mySlides2" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
   <img src="pic2.jpg" class="mySlides2" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
   <img src="pic3.jpg" class="mySlides2" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```